# Change column name of pandas DataFrame after groupby with duplicate name in header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two column TimeStamp (date type) and Value. I want to aggregate by year and hour and value is the average value.

```
df.groupby([df["TimeStamp"].dt.year,df["TimeStamp"].dt.hour]).mean()
```

The result is:

```
                       Value
TimeStamp   TimeStamp
2014        0          4643.733325
            1          4278.877103
...
```

I want to flat the header and rename the column to Year, Hour, Value. But I can't use `.reset_index()` since the name TimeStamp is duplicate. 
I tried to use

```
df.groupby([df["TimeStamp"].dt.year,df["TimeStamp"].dt.hour],as_index=False).mean().reset_index()
```

but TimeStamp columns lost all the value

```
        index      Value
0       0          4643.733325
1       1          4278.877103
...
```

How can I have

```
Year   Hour   Value
2014   1      4643.7
       2      4278.8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rename`:

```
rng = pd.to_datetime(['2014-04-03', '2014-04-03 01:01:00', '2014-05-03'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp': rng, 'value': range(3)})  
print (df)
            TimeStamp  value
0 2014-04-03 00:00:00      0
1 2014-04-03 01:01:00      1
2 2014-05-03 00:00:00      2

s = df.groupby([df["TimeStamp"].dt.year.rename('Year'),
                df["TimeStamp"].dt.hour.rename('Hour')]).mean()
print (s)
           value
Year Hour       
2014 0         1
     1         1
```

Or set MultiIndex names by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
s = df.groupby([df["TimeStamp"].dt.year,
                df["TimeStamp"].dt.hour]).mean()

s = s.rename_axis(['Year','Hour'])
#another solution
#s.index.names = ['Year','Hour']
print (s)
           value
Year Hour       
2014 0         1
     1         1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it this:

```
df.groupby([df["TimeStamp"].dt.year,
        df.rename(columns={"TimeStamp":"TimeStamp_1"})["TimeStamp_1"].dt.hour]).mean()
```